# My unattended silent.xml of VS2012 is not installing the CORE

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-installer, silent-installer

I'm in a big trouble, i've created this unattended xml to install VS2012, but is not installing me the CORE files neede to run VS  (the package vs_ultimatecore.msi that contains: devenv.exe, vsixintaller, and all the necessary to run VS...)

What I need to do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<AdminDeploymentCustomizations xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2011/AdminDeployment">  
<BundleCustomizations TargetDir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0" NoWeb="no"/>  
<SelectableItemCustomizations>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="WebTools" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="OfficeTools" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SharepointTools" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/>   
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="LightSwitch" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SilverLight_Developer_Kit" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQL" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/> 
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="VC_MFC_Libraries" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="Blend" Hidden="no" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="BlissHidden" Selected="yes"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="HelpHidden" Selected="no"/>   
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="IntelliTraceUltimateHidden" Selected="yes"/> 
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="LocalDBHidden" Selected="no"/> 
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="NetFX4Hidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="NetFX45Hidden" Selected="yes"/> 
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="PortableDTPHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="PreEmptiveDotfuscatorHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="PreEmptiveAnalyticsHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="ProfilerHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="ReportingHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="RIAHidden" Selected="no"/>   
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SDKTools3Hidden" Selected="yes"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SDKTools4Hidden" Selected="yes"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="Silverlight5DRTHidden" Selected="no"/>   
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLCEHidden" Selected="no"/> 
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLCEToolsHidden" Selected="no"/> 
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLCLRTypesHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLDACHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLDbProviderHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLDOMHidden" Selected="no"/> 
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQLSharedManagementObjectsHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="StoryboardingHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="TSQLHidden" Selected="no"/> 
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCCompilerHidden" Selected="no"/> 
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCCoreHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCDebugHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCDesigntimeHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="VCExtendedHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="WCFDataServicesHidden" Selected="yes"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="WinJSHidden" Selected="no"/>  
 <SelectableItemCustomization Id="WinSDKHidden" Selected="no"/>  
</SelectableItemCustomizations>  
</AdminDeploymentCustomizations>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare:

```
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="WebTools" Hidden="no" Selected="yes"/>
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="OfficeTools" Hidden="no" Selected="yes"/>
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="SharepointTools" Hidden="no" Selected="yes"/>
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="LightSwitch" Hidden="no" Selected="yes"/>
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="SilverLight_Developer_Kit" Hidden="no" Selected="yes" />
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="SQL" Hidden="no" Selected="yes" />
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="VC_MFC_Libraries" Hidden="no" Selected="yes" />
<SelectableItemCustomization Id="Blend" Hidden="no" Selected="no" />
```